# Jquery boolean if variable's children contains a class

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/yrJPE/2/

This works:

```
if (thediv.find('.theclass1').length) {
     alert('id1 has class1');   
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
if (thediv.hasClass('theclass1')) {
     alert('id1 has class1...');   
}
```

I'm looking for something concise and/or efficient...

BTW I'm actually using $(this) instead of thediv...

Comment: This updated code will help you to understand it better http://jsfiddle.net/yrJPE/3/

Comment: Hi I don't think I can use $('#id1 div'); because I'm using $(this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If brevity is your goal then the following works, albeit, internally, jQuery converts it back to the form you had in your original version:

```
if ($('.theclass1',  this).length) {
    alert('id1 has class1');   
}
```

This looks for all elements of the class `theclass1` within the context of `this`, or `$(this)`.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! =)

Answer (score 2):

The two ifs check for different things!

The first one checks if thediv contains an element matching the selector .class1

The second one checks if thediv has the class class1.

Based on what you really need to check you should pick the correct one, which is already concise.

Comment: I wonder if there's something more concise than if(thediv.find('.theclass1').length)

Comment: Using $('.theclass1', this).length is a little bit shorter but also a little less readable IMHO

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 2nd code works, replace it with:

```
if (thediv.find().hasClass('theclass1')) {
     alert('id1 has class1...');   
}
```

Comment: I just tried hasClass because I was looking for something shorter than the other one

Comment: @LukeWenke: Also you can use `thediv.find('.theclass1').length`

Comment: This is very inefficient because it can't leverage on `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: @ABFORCE http://api.jquery.com/size/ "The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead.

The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call."

Comment: @LukeWenke : You are right, the David's answer is better and shorter